# Monitoring of QtOpcUa value works only for one node

Tags: qt, opc-ua, qt6, qtopcua

I have a Qt6 console application that runs on Ubuntu 22.04.
The application connects to several OpcUa-enabled PLCs. The goal is to monitor some node values (all of class `variable`).

*Please note: I try to show you my code, of course I cannot provide a "complete" example since there is no way to simulate the actual remote machine. Of course, feel free to ask any further details that may help.*

First my struct to handle the nodes:

```
typedef struct
{
    QOpcUaNode *node; // the actual OpcUa node
    QVariant value;   // some internal variables,
    bool updated;     // not important for the question
    bool enableRead;
} Node_t;

void MyOpcUa::insertNode(QString key, QString id, bool enableRead)
{
    Node_t node; // my internal struct
    node.node = _opcUaClient->node(id); // retrieve the actual node
    node.value = QVariant();
    node.updated = false;
    node.enableRead = enableRead;

    Q_ASSERT(node.node); // check the node is valid

    _mapOpcNodes.insert(key, node);
    connect(node.node, &QOpcUaNode::attributeRead, this, &MyOpcUa::handleAttributes);
    connect(node.node, &QOpcUaNode::attributeUpdated, this, &MyOpcUa::handleAttributes);
    // when it reads the attributes I expect `handleAttributes` is called
}
```

Here how I connect to the remote machine:

```
void MyOpcUa::createClient()
{
    if (_opcUaClient)
    {
        delete _opcUaClient;
        _opcUaClient = nullptr;
    }

    Q_ASSERT(_opcUaClient == nullptr);

    if (_opcUaClient == nullptr)
    {
        _opcUaClient = _opcUaProvider->createClient(OPC_UA_BACKEND);
        if (!_opcUaClient)
        {
            qInfo() << ID << _name << "Connection to server failed:" << _opcUaClient->error();
            return;
        }

        connect(_opcUaClient, &QOpcUaClient::connectError, this, &MyOpcUa::connectError);
        _opcUaClient->setApplicationIdentity(_identity);
        _opcUaClient->setPkiConfiguration(*_pkiConfig);

        if (_opcUaClient->supportedUserTokenTypes().contains(QOpcUaUserTokenPolicy::TokenType::Certificate))
        {
            QOpcUaAuthenticationInformation authInfo;
            authInfo.setCertificateAuthentication();
            _opcUaClient->setAuthenticationInformation(authInfo);
        }

        connect(_opcUaClient, &QOpcUaClient::connected, this, &MyOpcUa::clientConnected);
        connect(_opcUaClient, &QOpcUaClient::disconnected, this, &MyOpcUa::clientDisconnected);
        connect(_opcUaClient, &QOpcUaClient::errorChanged, this, &MyOpcUa::clientError);
        connect(_opcUaClient, &QOpcUaClient::stateChanged, this, &MyOpcUa::clientState);
        connect(_opcUaClient, &QOpcUaClient::endpointsRequestFinished, this, &MyOpcUa::getEndpointsComplete);
        connect(_opcUaClient, &QOpcUaClient::findServersFinished, this, &MyOpcUa::findServersComplete);
    }
}
```

Then, after the connection, I enable the monitoring of the list of nodes:

```
void MyOpcUa::enableMonitoring()
{
   QMapIterator<QString, Node_t> i(_mapOpcNodes);
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        i.next();
        Node_t node = i.value();
        if (node.enableRead)
        {
            qDebug() << node.node->enableMonitoring(QOpcUa::NodeAttribute::Value, QOpcUaMonitoringParameters(1000));
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the returned value of `enableMonitoring` calls and all are `true`.
The problem is only one node is actually read periodically. I know this since this is the handler:

```
void MyOpcUa::handleAttributes()
{
    QOpcUaNode *node = qobject_cast<QOpcUaNode*>(sender());
    QString key = retrieveNode(node->nodeId());
    if (key.isEmpty())
    {
        qWarning() << ID << "Key not found" << key;
    }

    QVariant value = node->attribute(QOpcUa::NodeAttribute::Value);    
    qDebug() << key; // print which node has been read

    if (_mapOpcNodes.contains(key))
    {
        _mapOpcNodes[key].updated = true;
        _mapOpcNodes[key].value = value;
        emit valueChanged(key, value);
    }
}
```

and only one `key` is printed. Of course, if I manually trigger a read I can read them all.
Using an OpcUa viewer I inspected some of the desired nodes:

[image]

and I didn't find any difference among them. By the way, the only node I can successfully monitoring is `udiActualOrderLengthRT`.

I searched for other questions and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68637076/opcua-c-monitored-item-doestn-callback-the-function) one. But, honestly I'm not sure if the answer is applicable to my framework as well.

I also read the [QOpcUaNode::enableMonitoring](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopcuanode.html#enableMonitoring) and [QOpcUaMonitoringParameters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopcuamonitoringparameters.html) documentation and if I understand correctly I can live with the default `SubscriptionType::Shared` mode since I want all the data to be read with the same interval.

Is there any evidence of error in my code or in my approach?
What can cause such a behavior?

### UPDATE

I also checked the `enableMonitoringFinished` signal:

```
void MyOpcUa::enableMonitoringFinished(QOpcUa::NodeAttribute attr, QOpcUa::UaStatusCode statusCode)
{
    qDebug() << attr << statusCode;
}
```

and it is a success:

```
QOpcUa::NodeAttribute::Value QOpcUa::Good
```

Comment: Wait a minute! I didn't find this information in the docs, but I assumed the monitoring should happen every 1000 ms (in my case). But **if the value has not changed, does the signal is emitted anyway?**. Or is it emitted *only* when the value changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPC UA Subscriptions are only update, after the initail value, if the value has changed. Otherwise there would be no advantage of polling the variables.